# Drupal 7: make nodes private (for authenticated users only) visible

Tags: drupal-7

Pretty much what the title says: How to make nodes private or 'visible to authenticated users only'?

I've looked at the drupal 6 module called [Private](http://drupal.org/project/private) there is some kind of [patch](http://drupal.org/node/1077600) for it, but i'm not really used to, and happy with, patches.

Isn't there a build-in function that I might have been overlooked?

[edit] visible for specified roles [/edit]

Comment: So what you want is that some specific nodes require log-in before they can be viewed? What nodes do you want to make private?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you only want to restrict access to particular content types, not all content (Drupal core lets you do that). Surprisingly, it looks like you need a contrib module for this. This one looks popular and well-supported: http://drupal.org/project/content_access

Comment: Not being able to control view access by content type OOB is definitely one of Drupal's Scooby moments. Node View Permissions http://dgo.to/node_view_permissions is another solution that adds this.